# How to redirect non www to www?

Tags: plugins, php

Helo gays, here is a website buhehe.de but it opens also in brows without www.  but i want to show it with www.buhehe.de
Here is htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

how can i make mz site www.buhehe.de? When i ordered a hosting there i typed buhehe.de and not www.buhehe.de  IS this problem? CAn i solve my problem with htaccess?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www this isn't a WP question

Answer (score 1):

Just below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried it but after that my website was shot down...

Comment: 99% in the wrold use www.domain.com

Comment: I used it and website is down now. see: http://buhehe.de/

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე You probably pasted snippet in the wrong place. I've updated my answer with a clearer instruction.